# What do I use for the Auth-Token when doing resumable uploads to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm reading through the google cloud storage [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) about resumable uploads and I'm unclear as to what I should include for the Auth-Token in the request header. The initial request they suggest using looks like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
  "name": "myObject"
}
```

I'm using an API key for my application, so I append the request URL with a key that looks like `&key=myAPIKey`.

I get a 401 response (`Invalid Credentials`), which I assume is because I'm not including the correct token in the request header.

My question is, what do I include in the Authorization request header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit after the "Bearer" is usually an "access token". Access tokens are short-lived credentials that allow you to authenticate your HTTP calls. They're the result of an OAuth flow of some sort. If you want to try things out manually and have the gcloud SDK installed, you can create one with this command:

```
$> gcloud auth print-access-token
```

Of course, that token will only last a few minutes, and you don't want to embed it into a program anyhow. Instead, you'll either acquire a private key for a service account or a refresh token for a real user, and then you'll have your program exchange that permanent credential for an access token using Google's OAuth 2 libraries. The protocol is documented, but Google also provides libraries that handle it, and I suggest using them. There's a lot more documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. So just to clarify, when I create a service account, the JSON file that gets automatically downloaded is the credential I can use in conjunction with a library to generate Auth-Token's on an as needed basis?

Comment: Just so. The JSON file contains a private key file and some other keys. It represents permission to authenticate as a particular service account. It's revokable but is otherwise valid forever. You will pass it to a library that will use it to sign a request for access tokens as needed.